# Urls amigables con Nextjs (Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de prueba para aprender next.js y me surge la duda a la hora de hacer las urls amigables.

Siguiendo la documentación, en la Card tengo lo siguiente

```
<Link href="/productos/[id]" as={`/productos/${id}`}>
    <img src={imageUrl} className="card-img-top p-4" />
</Link>
```

En [id].js tengo lo siguiente:

```
    // Routing para obtener el id actual
    const router = useRouter();
    const { query: { id }} = router;

    // context de firebase
    const { firebase, usuario } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(id && consultarDB) {
            const obtenerProducto = async () => {
                const productoQuery = await firebase.db.collection('coches').doc(id);
                const producto = await productoQuery.get();

                if(producto.exists) {
                    guardarProducto(producto.data());
                    guardarConsultarDB(false);
                } else {
                    guardarError(true);
                    guardarConsultarDB(false);
                }
                
            }
            obtenerProducto();
        }
    }, [id]);
```

He intentado crear un slug, pero a la hora de cambiar esto no me ha funcionado:

```
const productoQuery = await firebase.db.collection('coches').doc(slug);
```

¿Alguna ayuda? Mil gracias!

Comment: Hola! Lograste resolver tu problema? Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Lo que comúnmente gestionas en React con un Hook, lo debes realizar con los métodos de NextJS dentro de LA PAGINA (no el componente, LA PAGINA): **getStaticProps** y **getServerSideProps**.

Por favor, lee los enlaces a continuación para que definas cuál te conviene más y si tienes más dudas, pregúntame sin problema:

getStaticProps
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticprops-static-generation

getServerSideProps
https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getserversideprops-server-side-rendering